# Spring Boot application - difference in startup time with "mvn spring-boot:run" and "java -jar"

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I noticed a big difference in the startup time of my Spring Boot application when starting with Maven and as jar. For example:

- `mvn spring-boot:run` - 5 seconds
- `java -jar myapp.jar` - 25 seconds

Starting the jar file takes like 5 times longer. Why is it so? What is happening in the background when starting the application with Maven and as jar? Is something loaded differently? And is it possible to start the jar file for the time used by Maven?

Comment: How did you measure the time?

Comment: I added `new Date()` before and after the `SpringApplication.run(MySpringBootApplication.class, args);` After that I logged the difference.

Comment: Could you also measure the time each process exists when using `<fork>true</fork>` for maven and `java -jar myapp.jar`?

Comment: This configuration does not seem to have any big influence on the startup time. The time messured for Maven with `<fork>true</fork>` and `<fork>false</fork>` is almost the same. `<fork>true</fork>` is even 0,2 seconds faster. Does that make any sense? And `java -jar myapp.jar` still takes like 4-5 time longer.

Answer (score 9):

This difference could be due to the fact that `spring-boot:run` is actually running the Spring Boot application inside Maven JVM (Unless you explicitly set the `fork` argument), When it does run inside Maven JVM it is actually running as a new Thread not a Process. Creating a Thread is much faster than a Process.

But `java -jar` command will create a OS Process, Process creation has steps attached to it like requesting a process id, allocating memory, etc. On top of that the `myapp.jar` will need to extracted plus the JVM will not have any optimization as it will be reading the `.class` extracted from the jar file for the first time. Basically a Cold Start which takes time.

You can see the source code for Maven Spring Boot Plugin [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/1.2.5.RELEASE/org/springframework/boot/maven/RunMojo.java)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. 
I tried it with `<fork>true</fork>` and `<fork>false</fork>` in my `pom.xml` but the result was the same - I still need only 5 seconds with Maven. 
I also unpacked `myapp.jar` and used `java -cp .\myapp org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher` but the result was the same - 25 seconds. 
What else could I try?

Comment: I find your answer hard to believe. Process creation does not take seconds, it takes milliseconds at most, microseconds probably. Running from maven does not change the fact that the classes have to be loaded and they are yet to be optimized by jvm.

Comment: I have some database initialisation at startup, that is why the process is very slow. But it doesn't change the fact that the startup with Maven is much faster. When I disable the initialisation of the database, I need like 2 seconds with Maven (it doesn't matter if `<fork>true</fork>` or `<fork>false</fork>`). Starting the jar takes like 7 seconds. It is still more than 3 times slower.

Comment: So, now I have created a simple "Hello World" project (Spring Boot + Thymeleaf). I have the following startup times: Maven (Run as... via Eclipse): 1,5 seconds; mvn spring-boot:run: 2 seconds; java -jar: 4,5 seconds. I have also tested with fork true and false, this doesn't have any influence on the time. Am I doing something wrong?